# Trying to run in powershell an XML string

Tags: powershell

Trying to run the following using PowerShell.

Using the following URL:

```
https://uat-somesite.com/folder/broker?ACTION=GETPREFS&REQUEST=<?xml%20version='1.0'%20encoding='utf-8'?><PreferencesRequest><IPAddress>10.10.10.10</IPAddress><Name>MACHINE-NAME</Name><PAN>0</PAN></PreferencesRequest>
```

Placing into PowerShell:

```
Invoke-WebRequest https://uat-somesite.com/folder/broker?ACTION=GETPREFS%26REQUEST=<?xml%20version='1.0'%20encoding='utf-8'?><PreferencesRequest><IPAddress>10.10.10.10</IPAddress><Name>MACHINE-NAME</Name><PAN>0</PAN></PreferencesRequest>
```

And get the resulting message:

```
Invoke-WebRequest : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a 
send.
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-WebRequest https://uat-somesite.com/folder/broker% ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [In 
   voke-WebRequest], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Invo 
   keWebRequestCommand
```

The XML string is:

```
<?xml%20version='1.0'%20encoding='utf-8'?>
<PreferencesRequest>
<IPAddress>10.10.10.10</IPAddress>
<Name>MACHINE-NAME</Name><PAN>0</PAN></PreferencesRequest>
```

I can take the following and paste into my browser fine.

```
https://uat-somesite.com/folder/broker?ACTION=GETPREFS&REQUEST=%3C?xml%20version=%271.0%27%20encoding=%27utf-8%27?%3E%3CPreferencesRequest%3E%3CIPAddress%3E10.10.10.10%3C/IPAddress%3E%3CName%3EMACHINE-NAME%3C/Name%3E%3CPAN%3E0%3C/PAN%3E%3C/PreferencesRequest%3E
```

I know we can encode and decode the string, but I feel that should not be needed.

Going a step further, we have also tried:

```
$URI="https://uat-somesite.com/folder/broker?ACTION=GETPREFS&REQUEST="
$Body = @"
<?xml%20version='1.0'%20encoding='utf-8'?>
<PreferencesRequest>
<IPAddress>10.10.10.10</IPAddress>
<Name>MACHINE-NAME</Name>
<PAN>0</PAN>
</PreferencesRequest>
"@

iwr $URI –infile $soap
```

and the result is:

```
iwr : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
At line:11 char:1
+ iwr $URI –infile $soap
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [In 
   voke-WebRequest], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Invo 
   keWebRequestCommand
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is the SSL cert self-signed?

Comment: Entrust is the certificate.  Not self-signed.